# Adding new worker threads in zeromq on load

Tags: multithreading, zeromq

There are plenty of examples of providing a multithreaded server in 0MQ, starting with:

http://zguide.zeromq.org/java:mtserver

but in all I've seen, the number of worker threads is set at startup.  While it's trivial to add worker threads at runtime, is there a canonical way of doing this in reaction to increased load in zero?  I wondered about detecting a high water mark hit and adding a thread at this point (but that may be too late)?

Comment: What language binding you using?

Comment: And how do you intend to detect HWM threshold? There's no easy way to do it.

Comment: @raffian, according to link he provide, I think he's using java

Comment: Why would you want to react to load by adding threads? Perhaps you are under the mistaken impression that you need more threads to do more work. That is not so.

Comment: Even I am in the same situation of Dean. When new request comes, a new thread should be spawned to address it. What kind of pattern should I use? Currently I am using paranoid pirate pattern.

Comment: I'm too in this situation now.
Imagine an application which basically does database operations. Those actions are mainly IO waits for the database. To have a fixed number of workers would mean to have as many workers as you allow database connections. Spring Datas default is e.g. 200. 
No. I don't want 200 workers and ZMQ sockets open if the application is idling for requests. There aren't 200 database connections open, too. Connections will be opened on demand and some will be closed again if the high load is over.

Comment: Now I don't see a problem on opening new workers on demand. Just count working workers with an AtomicInteger (and decrement the number if a worker is done with its work) and open new workers if all workers are busy.

The problem is to close a ZMQ socket gracefully. Yes, you can disconnect a socket and read all remaining messages. But you can't respond to them anymore because the socket is disconnected.

I can't see a way of dynamic scaling and being gentle on resources with ZMQ. It's either one or the other but not both.